# select unique values from a column order by count

Tags: php, mysql

I use this code:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(name) AS name FROM Tags  ORDER BY name DESC"
```

But how can I ORDER it via count of values?

something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(name) AS name FROM Tags  ORDER BY count(name) DESC"
```

Comment: when you are selecting using  'distinct' how can you count the name in same query? As the count will always be 1 for every name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/01ca2/2)

```
SELECT count(name) as count, name
FROM Tags
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY count DESC;
```