# SELECT DISTINCT and ORDER BY number of same values

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by, distinct

MY CODE: What functions do I need to perform such function?

```
SELECT DISTINCT word
FROM Table
ORDER BY ??? -- number of equal words in descending order
```

---

EXAMPLE: I HAVE THE FOLLOWING DATA

```
Word
----
are
are
are
we
we
we
we
is
is
you
```

---

DESIRED OUTPUT: (After running the query)

```
Word
----
we
are
is
you
```

Comment: How would you want to  order ties?  should it be by count desc then by word?  If there was one more 'are' should it be `are we is you` order then? or should it be `we are is you`?

Comment: It does not matter, thanks for clarifying. Though I still want to know what would it be if it was in the 'are we is you' order?

Comment: `order by count(*) desc, word asc` or `order by count(*) desc word desc`;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [select unique values from a column order by count](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29022176/select-unique-values-from-a-column-order-by-count)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `GROUP BY` and then `ORDER`:

```
SELECT word
FROM Table
GROUP BY Word
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: How is this ordered as he asked for?

Comment: @sagi ...how is it not?

Comment: Sorry, wasn't paying attention.